# What does getClass().getResource() point to?

Tags: java, path, getresource

In Java, Eclipse, what location does this line of code refer to?

```
this.getClass().getResource()
```

Does it give me the project folder? Or the package folder? Or anything else?

How exactly should one work with this?

Comment: It points to the generated `/bin` folder. Don't work with that. Put your files in the appropriate location in the source folders.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getClass().getResource("/")
```

it refers to root of your output directory (`target/classes` or any other output directory configured in your ide configuration if IDE is the case)

Answer (score 0):

the same directory where your class file is located.

for example, you have an eclipse project with a x.y.z.My.java in the src dir

if it's compiled to x.y.z.My.class in the bin dir

then if this() is My.class, this will point to bin/x/y/z

Answer (score 0):

GetResources is reffering to the location related all the packages in your CLASSPATH it means target/classes.
Classpath and target can be configured depends on the IDE. For instance for Intellij :
project properties->modules->paths

Comment: It depends on the idee configuration, by default in target.

Comment: Please add that to your answer, ideally with details how you can check your configuration.

Comment: First of all who says that I have to work with eclipse ;) I'm using Intellij.

Comment: The question is about eclipse.